# How to get SendKeys Method to Work with LeanFT?

Tags: c#, methods, hp-uft, leanft

In UFT it is pretty straight forward; however, when attempting to use the SendKeys method insert some simple text, the syntax apparently is not correct.  Anyone used SendKeys with LeanFT?

Comment: Have you reviewed this link for the details?
http://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/NetSDKReference/HP.LFT.SDK~HP.LFT.SDK.ISupportSendKeys~SendKeys(String).html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I did look there; however, when using what I thought would bring up the SendKeys method, it did not work.  It is probably me being new to programming, expecially C#.  What I am trying to do is after dumping text in a text field using setvalue just hit the return key afterwards.

Comment: What kind of application are you interacting with? Web, .NET, Java?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the object that you used to set the text with you then SendKeys. This example is given in Java, but it should be similar in C#.

```
object.SetText("example text");
object.SendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```